# Process substitution working in bash but not is zsh

Tags: bash, zsh, process-substitution

I'm trying to feed to a while loop using process substitution.

```
logFile=$1
declare -A frequencyMap

while read line
do

 name=$(echo $line | awk '{print $11}')

 if [ ${frequencyMap[$name]+_} ]

   then frequencyMap[$name]=$(expr ${frequencyMap[$name]} + 1)

   else frequencyMap[$name]=1

 fi

done < <(zgrep 'PersonalDetails' $logFile)

for key in "${!frequencyMap[@]}"
do 
 echo "$key ${frequencyMap[$key]}"
done | sort -rn -k2
```

This works fine in bash but not in zsh. I'm getting this error:

```
test.sh: line 20: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
test.sh: line 20: `done < <(zgrep 'Exception' $1)'
```

I'm using zsh 4.3.10.

How do I get this to work in zsh?

UPDATE: have modified the question to share the complete code

Comment: What version of `zsh` and how exactly is it not working there?

Comment: It is a simplified example. I'm doing much more stuff inside the while loop in the actual script.

Comment: `< <(stuff)` is a bashism. I doubt it is defined in `zsh`. Try command substitution `zgrep 'Exception' $1 | while...` instead.

Comment: So it seems. How do I go about converting this to.... zshism? :|

Comment: Try the straight piping of the command `zgrep 'Exception' $1 | while...` mentioned above. Also what version of `zsh` are you using (`zsh --version`)?

Comment: `zsh` is supposed to support process substitution (it did in a quick test for me (of version 4.2.6 on CentOS 5) and is listed as supporting it at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution). I suppose it could be a compile-time feature or something though. Are you sure you are testing with `zsh` there and not `/bin/sh` (or `zsh` in some `sh`-compat mode)?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to differentiate between them. 
However, "echo $0"  gives me "-zsh". 
And "zsh --version" gives me "zsh 4.3.10 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)"

Comment: According to [this page](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_7.html), you can use this syntax `=( ... )`. I don't have zsh to test it though

Comment: Use `${(k)frequencyMap}` to get the keys.

Comment: @mindreader You may be running the script *from* `zsh`; are you sure you are running the script *with* `zsh`? That is, what command do you use to run the script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the much more common pipe for this, instead:

```
zgrep 'PersonalDetails' "$logFile" |
{
  while read line
  do
    # ...
  done

  for key in "${(k)frequencyMap[@]}"
  do 
    echo "$key ${frequencyMap[$key]}"
  done | sort -rn -k2
}
```

Not only is this more portable, I consider it more readable because the flow starts with opening the input file.

Thanks to @user000001 for pointing out the fact that braces must be used to compose the commands so `frequencyMap` is visible outside the `while` loop.  For why that's necessary, see here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: @user000001: which variable are you referring to?

Comment: @user000001: thanks for that, I've fixed it now (I think!).

Comment: Ah! I was doing it like this initially but i changed it because of local variable issue. I'll try it with braces. Thanks!

Comment: The braces aren't necessary in `zsh`, though; the last command in a pipeline executes in the current shell, not a subshell.